# 'cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken' decrypt() are not decrypted data that's returned from the encrypt()

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, python-cryptography

I building simple password manager app to improve my python skill, but I came across annoying problem, my app take the new password and store it in json file, the key are the name that reference to the encrypted password, the user type the name of his/her account and the app go to the json file and take encrypted password and decrypt it and save it in the `clipboard`

here some example

```
json file
{
"passOne":"gAAAAABkL2MK5VuKJHZ7OjasQ9QggomOZaLX7wH43cQMbl" 
} 

python file

   # imagine here I check if the password is not in a json file so I ask the user if want to add it or not, if so I use Fernet.encrypt() and add to the json file.
   # load the json file
   with open('j.json','r') as _F:
       data = json.load(_F)

   # now here the error start
   password = Fernet.decrypt(data.get(#name of the password).encode())
```

it throw this error

> ```
> raise InvalidSignature("Signature did not match digest.")
> cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest.
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> # some paths 
> raise InvalidToken
> cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
> ```

Comment: You need to actually *call* the `.encode()` method, not just mention it by name.